# Modeling and counteracting exposure bias in recommender systems

Tags: machine-learning, causality, bias, recommender-system

I am looking for best strategies to train a new recommendation model from the biased data (due to modeling bias from the previous model).

For e.g. Lets assume I have an e-commerce site and initially I am recommending all the products randomly to the users. In order to improve the personalization, I train modelA (e.g. MF model) using this historical data(6 months) collected from the random system. Model performs better than the random approach and it gets deployed. Now, all the users are seeing recommendations from this modelA.

6 months later, I want to train a new model modelB (e.g. DL). How would I go about training this new model? All the training data is biased because of the modelA. Are there any good practices to handle this?
I have found this paper close to this topic https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5956

Answer (score 2):

After spending some time with my friend Google, I found this paper "Doubly Robust Policy Evaluation and Learning" close to what I could use for my task (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4601.pdf).
I'm still looking for any new methods other than this.